# Can clipping the context before drawing help HTML5 canvas performance?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I'm looking at the workings of an HTML5 game framework, and was wondering about a particular optimization it makes.

The framework keeps track of "dirty" ares of the screen that might have changed.  If an entity overlaps with such an area, then it is redrawn.  First, however, the context is clipped to only the dirty area.

Is this faster than simply redrawing the entire image?  What about if the entity is rendered through a more complicated series of canvas commands?

*e:* After thinking about it a little more, I realized there's a reason why clipping is vital in the context of the game framework, regardless of performance.  I am still kinda curious about that, though, so I'll leave the question up as is.

Comment: Interesting question.Looking forward to see answers/suggestions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was my last question edited out?

Comment: I would think it'd depend on a lot of things, including the video card and the JS engine. I have found that touching the context a lot in Firefox can have drastic performance implications, but Chrome is just fine, for example.

Comment: The most expensive operation when dealing with canvas in my experience is the actual draw calls on a context. Operations done on the canvas outside of the active clipping area is (should be) ignored by the renderer completely. If the entity is large and only a small area of it is touching the dirty area, e.g. a large background that also needs to be redrawn for some reason (e.g. an animated tile map), ignoring everything outside the dirty area will have *significant* performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on one hand you save time by not rendering the entities that don't intersect dirty areas. But, on the other hand you lose time because canvas oprations with clipping are slower.

Some browsers (Chrome) keep track of the canvas region you painted in and update only that part of the screen. It also saves some time.

So whether such thing can help depends on how large are dirty areas are (if the dirty area is almost as large as whole canvas it is faster to redraw everything without clipping) and how many objects you have (the more you have the more time you can save). I guess most of the times it is worth doing. Repainting everything each frame must be really slow.